# Mysql: Update records in one table that have exactly one reference in an n:m relation

Tags: mysql

I have the tables *fruits*, *vegetables* and *fruits_vegetables*. I have to update those *fruits* records that have exactly one related *vegetables* record.

When joining *fruits_vegetables* with *fruits* and grouping by *fruits.id* and counting, the result will not be updateable as query results of a query containing a group statement are not updateable.

So now I did this in phpmyadmin to test:

```
SELECT 
fruits.*,
(SELECT count(*)
   FROM fruits_vegetables fv 
   WHERE fv.fruit_id=f.id) AS rel_count
FROM fruits f
HAVING rel_count = 1
```

It seems that aggregating with count(*) still prevents the result of the query from being updateable.

Is there another way to update those *fruits* records that have a relation to exactly one *vegetable* record?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: `UPDATE t JOIN t1 JOIN(SELECT col FROM somet GROUP BY col HAVING COUNT=1)x ON t.somecol=x.col SET col2=someval` This is the general direction,you JOIN the aggregate query which checks for count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `join` the results together:

```
update fruits f join 
       (select fv.fruit_id, count(*) as cnt
        from fruits_vegetables fv
        group by fruit_id
        having count(*) = 1
       ) fv
       on fv.fruit_id = f.id
    set f.isUnique = 1; -- Or whatever you want to set
```

I am assuming that "one vegetable record" means "one record in `fruits_vegetables`, which is suggested by the sample code.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much! As you count the number of referenced records into a field *cnt* you can also do *having cnt = 1*